# What is the meaning of view dependencies?

Tags: sql, ssms

What is the meaning of view dependencies in sql studio management system, how can a column depend on other column and how are they related to each other ?

Comment: Reads like exam question :)

Answer (score 0):

> **SQL dependencies** are the **by-name references** that are used in SQL
>   expressions that make **one entity reliant on another entity**. An entity
>   that references another entity in its definition and that definition
>   is stored in the system catalog is called a referencing entity. An
>   entity that is referred to by another entity is called a referenced
>   entity.

Detailed info here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345449(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

view dependencies shows you all database object that are either dependent on the selected object or that the selected object depends on.
i.e if you have a view, you can see all the tables it is using.

[from TechNet:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345449%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> SQL dependencies are the by-name references that are used in SQL expressions that make one entity reliant on another entity.
>   An entity that references another entity in its definition and that definition is stored in the system catalog is called a **referencing entity**.
>   An entity that is referred to by another entity is called a **referenced entity**.